# Unable to get cart item in custom phtml - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, cart

I am trying to get cart items info in my module's phtml file:

```
/app/code/Essence/Fcf/view/frontend/templates/packages.phtml
```

Here is my working url: http://essence.onlineprojectprogress.com/packages

And this is my code:

```
<?php
    $cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart'); 

    // retrieve quote items collection
    $itemsCollection = $cart->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();

    // get array of all items what can be display directly
    $itemsVisible = $cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();

    // retrieve quote items array
    $items = $cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();

    foreach($items as $item) {
        echo 'ID: '.$item->getProductId().'<br />';
        echo 'Name: '.$item->getName().'<br />';
        echo 'Sku: '.$item->getSku().'<br />';
        echo 'Quantity: '.$item->getQty().'<br />';
        echo 'Price: '.$item->getPrice().'<br />';
        echo "<br />";            
    }
?>
```

But I am getting nothing. What wrong I am doing?

[image]

Comment: Did you initialize objectmanager ?

Comment: Yes, that is already.

Comment: In which page you are trying to achieve this?

Comment: /app/code/Essence/Fcf/view/frontend/templates/packages.phtml

Comment: Is this your custom module (or) 3rd party plugin?

Comment: yes. it is custom module.

Comment: it is my custom.

Comment: did you add your template file to xml ?

Comment: yes that is added.

Comment: Your code is proper and it is working.
can you please check your code is on same page you are seeing on frontend. The URL you provided is CMS page so you need to call your phtml file in CMS page by doing: {{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="[VendorName]_[ModuleName]::[YourTemplateFileLocation].phtml"}}

Comment: @ArshadHussain Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In magento, if you want to add template file(**.phtml**) in any cms page, then you need to use below code:

**Default Formula :**

```
{{block class="[Block_Class_Full_Name]" template="[VendorName]_[ModuleName]::[Your_Template_File_Location].phtml"}}
```

**Using Default block:**

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="[VendorName]_[ModuleName]::[Your_Template_File_Location].phtml"}}
```

**This is equal to Magento 1.X version code**

```
{{block type="core/template" template="Your_Template_File_Location.phtml"}}
```

Comment: I already used this and phtml rendering correctly but what I am not getting is cart item, subtotal etc.

Comment: @ArshadHussain Your code is working fine for me. also check the store for your page.

Answer (score 0):

You will get empty cart array if you are trying to get cart items on pages that can be cached. Like PDP, Homepage, etc

If you add `cacheable="false"` in your layout XML where you are calling the cart items, it will work fine.

For example, `cacheable="false"` in catalog_product_view.xml and then try to call cart items on this page, it will work fine. Otherwise, it will return NULL

Thanks [to this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/292109/21432)