# How to get all products of the Cart on HomePage. Magento2

Tags: magento2, cart, popup

I'm trying to get all the products of the cart for that I'm trying

```
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart;
$this->_cart = $cart;
public function getCartProducts(){

        $itemsCollection = $this->_cart->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();
    //    echo"<pre>"; print_r($itemsCollection->getData()) ;

        // get array of all items what can be display directly
        $itemsVisible = $this->_cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
        // print_r($itemsVisible) ;
        // retrieve quote items array
        $items = $this->_cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();
        print_r($items) ;
        echo"Asad";
        foreach($items as $item) {
            echo 'ID: '.$item->getProductId().'<br />';
            echo 'Name: '.$item->getName().'<br />';
            echo 'Sku: '.$item->getSku().'<br />';
            echo 'Quantity: '.$item->getQty().'<br />';
            echo 'Price: '.$item->getPrice().'<br />';
            echo "<br />";            
        }
```

When I run this code then it returns me *Null Array* in case of `$items = $this->_cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();` and `$VissibleItems = $this->_cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();` While in this case `$itemsCollection = $this->_cart->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();` it returns me many products which are not even added in cart. So how can I get all the products of the cart?? 
**NOTE:** I'm doing this on Localhost (Luma) and I'm doing this for guest user

**Edited:** I can get the data `http://127.0.0.1/magento/checkout/cart/` but on *homepage* I cannot get the data I want to get the data on *homepage* because on homepage I get *Null Array*
On homepage it do not return any data
[image]
but on Cart page it shows data 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I got an Answer... it will always return an **empty array** if I want to get the data in **Homepage** or any other page except **cart page** so the solution is we make to `cacheable=false` in *layout* like in my case my layout was

> Vender/Module/view/frontend/layout/default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Inchoo\ModalOverlay\Block\ModalOverlay"
                   template="Inchoo_ModalOverlay::modal_overlay.phtml"
                   name="modalOverlay"
                   as="modalOverlay" cacheable="false"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

as you can see at the end of the **block** I write `cacheable = 'false'` after just doing this simple step you'll get you cart products in every other page.

> IMPORTANT NOTE: Declaring **any** block's cacheable status as `false` within
> `default.xml` will essentially disable full page cache for the entire
> site.

Answer (score 1):

This code will allow you to get all items of cart.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart'); 

// get quote items collection
$itemsCollection = $cart->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();

// get array of all items what can be display directly
$itemsVisible = $cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();

// get quote items array
$items = $cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();

foreach($items as $item) {
    echo 'ID: '.$item->getProductId().'<br />';
    echo 'Name: '.$item->getName().'<br />';
    echo 'Sku: '.$item->getSku().'<br />';
    echo 'Quantity: '.$item->getQty().'<br />';
    echo 'Price: '.$item->getPrice().'<br />';
    echo "<br />";            
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I tried this code your code n my code are exactly same but it returns me the null array

Answer (score 0):

Your Block

```
public function getQuoteData()
    {
        $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote();
        if (!$this->hasData('quote')) {
            $this->setData('quote', $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote());
        }
        return $this->_getData('quote');
    }
```

Call the Block in your template

```
// Get all visible items in cart
$quote = $block->getQuoteData();

foreach($quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $_item) {
    echo 'ID: '.$_item->getProductId().'<br/>';
    echo 'Name: '.$_item->getName().'<br/>';
    echo 'Sku: '.$_item->getSku().'<br/>';
    echo 'Quantity: '.$_item->getQty().'<br/>';
    echo 'Price: '.$_item->getPrice().'<br/>';
    echo 'Product Type: '.$_item->getProductType().'<br/>';
}
```

Comment: is `$this->_checkoutSession` is object of `Magento\Checkout\Model\Session` this class??? and also explain `$this->_getData()` as well

Comment: n the most important question is did you get the data in homepage???

Comment: Yes you're right. $this->_getData() will get value from _data array without parsing key.

Comment: did you declare `$this->_getData()` in di???

Answer (score 0):

**use the session to get the quote and your cart items.**

```
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session;

public function __construct(
        ...
        Session $session
        ...
    ) {
        ...
        $this->_session = $session;
        ...
    }

public function yourFunction()
{
    $items = $this->_session->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
    print_r($items->getData());
}
```